# How should I use Azure Blob Containers?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

My current approach is that I have a few containers:

- raw (the actual raw files or exports, separated into folders like servicenow-cases, servicenow-users, playvox-evaluations, etc.)
- staging (lightly transformed raw data)
- analytics (these are Parquet file directories which consolidate and partition the files)
- visualization (we use a 3rd party tool which syncs with Azure Blob, but only CSV files currently. This is almost the exact same as the analytics container)

However, it could also make some sense to create more containers and kind of use them like I would use a database schema. For example, one container for ServiceNow data, another for LogMeIn data, another for our telephony system, etc.

Is there any preferred approach?

Comment: Hi, if my answer answered your question, can you mark it as the answer of this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description, it seems you are tangled to use a small number of containers to store a large number of blobs or make a large number of containers to store a small number of blobs. If all you think about is parallelism and scalability, you can rest assured,  just you design a storage structure that suits you. Because partitioning in Azure Blob storage is done at the blob level, not the container.

Each of these two approaches has their advantages and disadvantages.

For a small number of containers, it can save the cost of creating containers (the operation of creating containers need you to pay for it). But at the same time, when you try to list the blobs in the container, the objects in it will be listed. If you still have a subset inside, you still need to continue to obtain, in this case the performance is less than the Lots of Container Solution. And at the same time, the security boundary you set will apply to all blobs in this container. This is not necessarily what you want.

For a large number of structured containers, more containers can set more security boundaries (custom access permissions, access control SAS signatures). It is also easy to list blobs, no more messy subsets are needed to catch. But again, its disadvantage is that it will have more consumption in creating containers (in extreme cases, it will increase a lot of costs. In general, it does not matter. a website that calculates costs: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?cdn=disable).